# Horizontal slide not working in AppIntroSlider npm in react native

Tags: react-native, android-scrollview, react-native-flatlist, android-nestedscrollview

Good day guys. I am trying to achieve a horizontal slide within "AppIntroSlider" from 'react-native-app-intro-slider'.

`import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';`

I looked through the npm of this package and I saw it uses horizontal scrolling FlatList for horizontally scrolling multiple pages. In each of the pages I am showing brief intro text and a code snippet from python that does not fit into the screen horizontally. The problem is that I can not scroll horizontally this code snippet within this FlatList item/page.

Piece of the code is here :

```
<ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} horizontal={true} >
   {
      <Snippet snippet={item.code} />
   }
</ScrollView>
```

The code does not fit into the screen horizontally with the actual code and its comments at the end of the line.

If horizontal scroll is not possible within FlatList what else can you suggest to view the whole code snippet.
Please take a look at the result :

[image]

As you see, the code snippet has to be scrolled horizontally to be able to see the whole code.
Please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it.
I just placed a button underneath a code snippet "Show Fullscreen Code Snippet" that shows the code snippet in a separate full screen added as a stack to stackNavigator.

```
<TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SnippetContainer', { snippet: item.code_block })}
                >
                    <View>
                        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Fullscreen Snippet</Text>
                    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```